# Joomla Component Updates XML File Parsing error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a paid component in Joomla and as per latest JED requirements all developers will have to provide compatibility with Joomla Update System, as a way to support a method to distribute security fixes, enhancements and new features. Toeing to the line I updated my component to a version `1.1.0` and gave the update server requirements in the installation file.

This is the extra code added to manifest.xml file

```
<updateservers>
    <server type="extension" name="Code Seller">https://www.scriptplaza.com/downloads/codeseller.xml</server>
</updateservers>
```

So anyone installing this version will get all further update notifications in the control panel. Next day I uploaded another version `1.1.1` with minor updates. As per update server requirements this update should be shown at the backend control panel update page where it shows updates for all extensions. Many extension updates were listed but not mine. I have been working on this for last 2 days without success. I feel I have some error in the update xml file hosted in my server. This is the codeseller.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<updates>
    <update>
        <name><![CDATA[Codeseller]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Paid Download Component]]></description>
        <element>pkg_codeseller</element>
        <type>package</type>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <infourl title="scriptplaza.com">http://www.scriptplaza.com</infourl>
        <downloads>
           <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">
            <![CDATA[https://scriptplaza.com/index.php?option=com_codeseller&amp;controller=order&amp;task=order.downloadupdates&amp;product_id=4]]>
           </downloadurl>
       </downloads>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer><![CDATA[Amreeta Ray]]></maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>http://www.scriptplaza.com</maintainerurl>
        <section>Testing</section>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.6"/>
    </update>
</updates>
```

I followed this tutorial https://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server. Is there anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all those having difficulty that I faced, I will give a solution that doent match with Joomla docs but it works. Which means Joomla docs needs to be updated. If you check this link https://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server they say

```
client - Required for modules and templates as of 3.2.0. - The client ID of the extension, which can be found by looking inside the #__extensions table. To date, use 0 for "site" and 1 for "administrator". Plugins and front-end modules are automatically installed with a client of 0 (site), but you will need to specify the client in an update or it will default to 1 (administrator) and then found update would not be shown because it would not match any extension. Components are automatically installed with a client of 1, which is currently the default.

    Warning: The tag name is <client> for Joomla! 2.5 and <client_id> for 1.6 and 1.7. If you use <client_id> (rather than <client>) on a 2.5 site, it will be ignored.
```

This is not the case actually when I checked my #__updates I saw that all language files have client id 0 but my extension had 1. So just to check I added `<client>0</client>` to my xml file. Voila it worked. So finally I get this which is complete update file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <updates>
        <update>
            <name><![CDATA[Codeseller]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[Paid Download Component]]></description>
            <element>pkg_codeseller</element>
            <client>0</client>
            <type>package</type>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <infourl title="scriptplaza.com">http://www.scriptplaza.com</infourl>
            <downloads>
               <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">
                <![CDATA[https://scriptplaza.com/index.php?option=com_codeseller&amp;controller=order&amp;task=order.downloadupdates&amp;product_id=4]]>
               </downloadurl>
           </downloads>
            <tags>
                <tag>stable</tag>
            </tags>
            <maintainer><![CDATA[Amreeta Ray]]></maintainer>
            <maintainerurl>http://www.scriptplaza.com</maintainerurl>
            <section>Testing</section>
            <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.6"/>
        </update>
    </updates>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can have a quick look at my update file:

```
https://www.svenbluege.de/index.php?option=com_ars&view=update&task=stream&format=xml&id=1
```

I'm using the Akkeba Release System which generates this XML automatically. Maybe you find the missing part by comparing it with your XML file.

The reference in the package looks like this:

```
<updateservers>
    <server type="extension" priority="1" name="Event Gallery">http://www.svenbluege.de/index.php?option=com_ars&amp;view=update&amp;task=stream&amp;format=xml&amp;id=1</server>
</updateservers>
```

In addition you can check if your update url is in the `#__update_sites` table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont see any difference.

Comment: Did you checked that table?

Comment: its already there. But it is unable to parse the xml file in my server. When I tried this code `<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://scriptplaza.com/downloads/codeseller.xml'));
 var_dump($xml);
?>` i was able to parse it. Only thing missing was the url. Is <![CDATA[ ignored by xml parser.

Comment: Did you tried it without using the CDATA part and add the plain download url?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your manifest.xml contains `<packagename>codeseller</packagename>` and match your update stream 
`<element>pkg_codeseller</element>`

**If you use Akeeba Release:**
I struggle the past 2 days as well, but for another reason that i still explain now as it may help other:

Akeeba release check the environment string in `/components/com_ars/View/Update/tmpl/stream.php`

It has to be "Environment Title" = "joomla" and "XML update stream platform" higher than 2.5 to produce `<client>` in update stream otherwise it produce `<client_id>`

i've lost 2 days since i was using "XML update stream platform" = ".*"

Will make a pull request to ask for removal of Joomla 2.5 support in Akeeba Release.